# Are skill points variable per level in Dragon Quest 8?

Tags: dragon-quest-viii

Finally got DQ8 for Playstation 2 - as I'm playing through, I'm noticing that the skill/ability points you gain per level is really variable and a little unbalanced.

Between levels 10-15, the hero and Yangus were both gaining up to 8 points per level, allowing for rapid gains in their respective skills. Then Angelo comes along and starts gaining a paltry 2-3 per level. Everyone is now approaching level 20 - and while most party members have broken 40 in their main weapon skill, Angelo hasn't even made 20.

I also spent some time grinding, and during that time I noticed skill point gains were a lot lower for the levels gained - but now that I'm back to the main story, they're improving again.

My question is this: are skill point gains set (e.g. will Yangus always gain 5 points at level 15), or do they change based on certain factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The skill points per level are constant, and each character will get 350 total (not including any gained by the use of Seeds of Skill) by the time they hit level 99.  However, their distribution across levels is different for the characters, at least until they start approaching the higher levels.  At that point, the points per level drop so that your incremental gains per experience level are relatively limited.

Angelo doesn't really start hitting his highest skill point gains per level until the 30's or so, where the Hero, Yangus, and Jessica all have bursts of high points per level in the teens and 20's.

There's a list of the skill point gains per level in [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/583527-dragon-quest-viii-journey-of-the-cursed-king/faqs/40285) - search for Skill Point Chart.